# Projectile Motion in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

So my friend and I are making some 2D game, we are using some custom character controller, so we are not using rigidbody2D. Now we have some sort of catapult which needs to eject the player in a projectile-motion style. 
We've done it for the catapult which shoots the player straight up
In inspector you can decide how much units do you want player to jump and how much does it need to get to reach max height. 
So here is the code for the catapult that shoots the player up.

`float ejectInicialY = (jumpHeight - ( player.physics.gravity * Mathf.Pow(timeToReachMaxHeight, 2) / 2)) / timeToReachMaxHeight;
float ejectVelocityY = ejectInicialY + player.physics.gravity * Time.deltaTime;
player.physics.playerVelocity = new Vector2(ejectVelocityY, 0f);`

I tried to apply the same formulas for the X coordinate, but it doesn't work well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ultimately a physics problem.

You are calculating current velocities by determining the acceleration of the object. Acceleration of an object can be determined from the net force acting on the object (F) and the mass of the object (m) through the formula `a = F / m`. I highly recommend reading [some explanations of projectile motion](http://www.ux1.eiu.edu/~cfadd/1150/03Vct2D/proj.html) and understanding the meaning of the motion equations you are using.

### Vertical Direction

For the vertical direction, the net vertical force during the jump (assuming no air drag, etc.) is `player.physics.gravity`. So you apply your motion formulas assuming a constant acceleration of `player.physics.gravity`, which you've seemed to have accomplished already.

### Horizontal Direction

Becausegravity does not commonly act in the horizontal direction, the net horizontal force during the jump (assuming no air drag, etc.) is `0`. So again you can apply your motion formulas, but this time using `0` as your acceleration. By doing this, you should realize that `velocityX` does not change (in the absence of net horizontal force). Therefore the X coordinate can be determined through (in pseudo-code) `newPositionX = startPositionX + Time.deltaTime * velocityX`

Comment: Hey groves, thanks for the answer. I think I didn't ask the question properly, your answer sure helped me a bit but I didn't come to the solution. The only thing I need is: I have the distance how far on the x axis a player should go, I have the max height the player should go, and I have the time by which the player must reach the max height, and i have an angle of PI/4. How to make initial X and Y speed out of those parameters. That is the question. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @kantagara: In that case, you need to solve for the initial `launchSpeed`. There are many approaches you can take (as explained in the page I linked). The total time the object is in the air (`totalAirTime`) is twice the time it takes to reach the maximum height, or `totalAirTime = timeToMaxHeight * 2`. Now solve `velocityX = totalDistanceX / totalAirTime`. Because `velocityX` doesn't change, `initialVelocityX = velocityX`. Now solve `initialLaunchSpeed = initialVelocityX/cos(launchAngle)`. Now solve `initialVelocityY = initialLaunchSpeed*sin(launchAngle)`

Comment: @kantagara: It's assumed that `launchAngle` is measured from the horizon (this is explained in detail in the page I linked).